# Singularity and interior dynamic libraries

Tags: singularity-container

I am currently working on getting a bigger (C++) project inside a Singularity container. So far, everything works well, until I try to execute the container image, in which it won't find a dynamic library file that I previously build inside the container:

```
./MyProject.img
/<some path>/MyExecutable: error while loading shared libraries: libmongocxx.so._noabi: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My first thought was that maybe the process of building this dependency inside the container did somehow not succeed, therefore I added `ls /usr/local/lib/` at the end of the `%post` section of my recipe to check on that, but everything there is fine:

```
+ ls /usr/local/lib/
[...]
libmongocxx.so
libmongocxx.so.3.6.0
libmongocxx.so._noabi
[...]
```

So my next thought was that maybe the basic library folder is for some reason not a part of the environment variables of my container, so I extended the `%post` section with

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/
```

still to no avail.

Is there some property of Singularity containers I am missing here? Do I need to somehow extract the dynamic library file to outside of the container? Or did I made some stupid mistake I just can't see here?

(I tagged the question only with `singularity-container` for now as I don't think this is anything specific to C++ here, but if somebody thinks otherwise feel free to add. My container uses `Bootstrap: docker From: ubuntu:18.04`, should that be relevant.)

Edit: I also explicitely gave the dynamic libraries execution rights, just in case, and printed their rights:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       20 Sep 10 10:51 libmongocxx.so._noabi -> libmongocxx.so.3.6.0
```

Didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that your local environment is overwriting the variables in the image. You can use `singularity run --cleanenv MyProject.img` to prevent your current environment from persisting into the container. If there are variables you *do* want to pass in there, you can `export SINGULARITYENV_SOMEVAR=foo` to have `SOMEVAR=foo` set in the container environment.

If that doesn't do it, modify the `%runscript` to have a `env | sort` in there so you can see exactly what's set when it's attempting to run your code.

Comment: Thanks, `export SINGULARITYENV_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/` did the trick.